# Possible to abstract this logic with macro?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have thousands of function wrappers which inside actually perform a similar logic like:

```
// a, b, ... are variable length parameters of different type

void API_Wrapper(hHandle, a, b, ..)
{
if (hHandle)
   return remote_API(hHandle, a, b, ..);
else
   return API(a, b, ..);
}
```

I want to use a macro to reuse the if-else logic so I can simply implement the function like this:

```
void API_Wrapper(hHandle, a, b, ..)
{
    API_CALL(api_name, hHandle, a, b, ..); // API_CALL is a macro
}
```

I didn't come up with a good way. (Note: I could solve it via ... and `__va_args__` but this extension is not supported by the compiler we currently use)

Anyone ever met the same problem and any idea?

Comment: Could you make two example instances of your wrapper so we can see how it "generalizes"?

Comment: compiler: msvc7.1, gcc3.4

example: 

API1_XX(int hServer, int a, int b, int c)
{
if (hServer)
{
return remote_API1(hServer, a, b, c);
}
else
{
return API1(a, b, c);
}

API2_XX(int hServer, float a, double b)
{
if (hServer)
{
return remote_API2(hServer, a, b);
}
else
{
return API2(a, b);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another trick, without variadic macro's:

```
#define API_CALL(hHandle, api_name, arguments) if (hHandle) return remote_##api_name arguments; else return api_name arguments;

void API_Wrapper(int hHandle, int a, double b, char c)
{
            API_CALL(hHandle, api_name, (a, b, c));
}
```

Which becomes:

```
void API_Wrapper(int hHandle, int a, double b, char c)
{
     if (hHandle) return remote_api_name (a, b, c); else return api_name (a, b, c);;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define separate API_CALL0, API_CALL1 etc:)
You may wanna look into something that will automate the whole API_Wrapper thing, btw

Answer (score 0):

```
#define API_CALL(api_name, hHandle, ...) if (hHandle) remote##api_name(hHandle, __VA_ARGS__); else api_name(hHandle, __VA_ARGS__);

void API_Wrapper(int hHandle, int a, double b, char c)
{
            API_CALL(api_name, hHandle, a, b, c);
}
```

Which becomes

```
void API_Wrapper(int hHandle, int a, double b, char c)
{
     if (hHandle) remoteapi_name(hHandle, a, b, c); else api_name(hHandle, a, b, c);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the __VA_ARGS__ is not portable right now and our compiler doesn't support it (msvc7.1, gcc3.4).

Comment: looks like a preprocessor thing

Answer (score 0):

Using   BOOST_PP_SEQ_XXXX you can write your wrapper table in a way similar to this:

```
WRAP_API(myfunc1, param(int, k) param(double, r) param(char*, s))
                               ^                ^
                               ^blank           ^blank

WRAP_API(myfunc2, param(int, k) )

....
```

without variadic macros you can use space separated list which is treated as single macro parameter + some preprocessor techics incapsulated in boost pp